# Blender debugging symbol files

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, windows

Are there anywhere available the newest Blender debugging symbol files for ms-windows (*.pdb)? Blender recently crashed a few times and I wanted to provide developers more information than only info about the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone can do a debug build and make these files available, but typically we don't do this.

However - you assume the person fixing the bug has ms-windows, MSVC - etc, however many devs use Linux and OSX.
Even ignoring this, the crash data alone often isn't enough, developers need to be able to reproduce the bug so they can change the code and prove that the bug is fixed (without the trouble of sending you an updated build and having you test - which would get very tedious/slow).

Normally its possible to provide a blend file and some steps to redo the bug which is better for devs so they can redo on their own platform.

Comment: I wanted the PDB files, such that I could extract the call stack during the crash - this information is valuable for the dev, who debugs the software regardless of OS he uses. The crash I discovered happens very randomly - sometimes after second render (repeatably a few times), sometimes never. That's why I wanted to provide some more information about the error. If publishing these PDB files is not much trouble, maybe it is worth doing? Even if 5% of users are devs like me, you'll get these 5% bug reports documented better.

Comment: Sure, providing a stack trace is handy to get an initial idea whats wrong, if you cant get PDB files you could build Blender from source and get a backtrace that way.

Comment: Yeeeeeea, but that requires me to download the sources, install VS2008, rebuild the Blender and then run it from the IDE. If I might have downloaded the PDB files (which you have anyway) that would take me a few minutes only :)

Comment: You could mail the `bf-committer` mailing list and ask (on Linux here so no PDB files).

Comment: Ok, thanks :) May the Force be with You all :)